# Simple PHP Selenium test doesn't work

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I have the following Selenium test in PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php');

class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://change-this-to-the-site-you-are-testing/");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/frontend_dev.php");
    try {
        $this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent("Local Coupons"));
    } catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
        array_push($this->verificationErrors, $e->toString());
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run it (by running "php filename.php") I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php on line 60
```

Which makes sense because the class isn't defined anywhere, but why not? I installed PHPUnit. It seems a little weird that a class called PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase wouldn't be included with PHPUnit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [read the docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/textui.html) for PHPUnit for the command line test runner. You can also just run 'phpunit --help' from the command line. I believe you'll find that you need to instead run something like

```
phpunit path/to/filename.php
```